# Wildcard expression when searching for sheet name in google sheets. Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, wildcard

Having an issue attempting to search for certain google sheets in a folder that are imported. 
Each google sheet that is imported, has a regular name then a unique ID. EX: Manual Export(1024508324)

I created a script that takes all the google sheets inside a folder to be imported into one master google sheet. Below:
'''

```
function getdata() {
  //declare multiple variables in one statement - Initial value will
  //be undefined
  var destinationSpreadsheet,destinationSS_ID,destsheet,destrange,file,files,
      sourcerange,sourceSS,sourcesheet,srcSheetName,sourcevalues;
  var pattern = /.Manual./;
  srcSheetName = (pattern)   
  destinationSS_ID = "1DmG5DuWmBqaImUuVvXrhH6mRRozsv7ksjYoFLbEhVGY";
  files = DriveApp.getFolderById("13Z0RSeWnzW9mbm1wnTOEQrkzxUFCdCZF").getFiles();
  destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSS_ID);
  destsheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master');  

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() !== "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      continue;
    };
    sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    sourcesheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
    //sourcesheet.getRange(start row, start column, numRows, number of Columns)
    sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange(2,1,sourcesheet.getLastRow()-1,13);
    sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

    //Write all the new data to the end of this data
    destrange = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master")
        .getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,sourcevalues.length,sourcevalues[0].length);

    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
  };
};
```

'''

The area where im having trouble is

```
 var pattern = /.Manual./;
      srcSheetName = (pattern)
```

I want it to find any document with the word "Manual" inside the name to be used in SrcSheetName. What is the best way to do this wildcard? I tried using ./Manual./ but that did not work.

Let me know,
Garrett Kidd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get all sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) and use [String#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) or [String#startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the correct sheet:

```
sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
sourcesheet = sourceSS.getSheets().find(sheet => 
  sheet.getName().includes("Manual"))
```

Comment: The main/important part is that you have to iterate through all of the sheets using `spreadsheet.getSheets()` and then check their name using `.getName()` to find the ones you want.